# How to find the mean of a column relative to another column?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, feature-engineering, kaggle

I am working on the Boston house price prediction.  I have a column named `GarageYrBlt` that holds the year the garage was built for a specific house.  My assumption is that the garage would most likely be built at the same time as the house so I want to fill the missing value with the median of the column `GarageYrBlt` relative to the column `YearBuilt`.

To explain my idea further:  While I was working on the Titanic problem, I filled the missing `Age` column with the median relative to the `Sex` column.  So all female passengers with the missing age would get the value that is the median age of all female passengers.

This is what I did:

```
train['GarageYrBlt'] = train['GarageYrBlt']
     .fillna(train.groupby('YearBuilt')['GarageYrBlt']
     .transform("median"), inplace=True)
```

And when I do `print(train['GarageYrBlt'])`, this is my output:

```
0       None
1       None
2       None
3       None
4       None
5       None
6       None
7       None
8       None
9       None
10      None
11      None
12      None
13      None
14      None
15      None
16      None
17      None
18      None
19      None
20      None
21      None
22      None
23      None
24      None
25      None
26      None
27      None
28      None
29      None
        ... 
1430    None
1431    None
1432    None
1433    None
1434    None
1435    None
1436    None
1437    None
1438    None
1439    None
1440    None
1441    None
1442    None
1443    None
1444    None
1445    None
1446    None
1447    None
1448    None
1449    None
1450    None
1451    None
1452    None
1453    None
1454    None
1455    None
1456    None
1457    None
1458    None
1459    None
Name: GarageYrBlt, Length: 1460, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `inplace` to `False` (which is the default).

Setting it to `True` changes the dataframe in place, so you don't have to assign the column again. Also, setting `inplace=True` returns `None`. So, either:

```
train['GarageYrBlt'] = train['GarageYrBlt']
     .fillna(train.groupby('YearBuilt')['GarageYrBlt']
     .transform("median"), inplace=False)
```

or

```
train['GarageYrBlt']
     .fillna(train.groupby('YearBuilt')['GarageYrBlt']
     .transform("median"), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Why does setting it to true return None?

Comment: Lots of discussion about this...
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1893

Comment: I tried your first snippet of code and the original nan value stays intact.

Comment: Hi, did you try re-reading the DataFrame?

Comment: How so??.......

Comment: Because after you have run your code in your question, the whole column is already `None`. So you have to `read_csv` or whatever to get back your original `GarageYrBlt` column (i.e. go back and revert to the original state).

Comment: So how do I solve that?  Just call `read_csv` twice?